# Opening PPT-Files

Tags: android, file, powerpoint, viewer

I want to open a PPT-file with my app. How can I check if there is an app that can display these files installed on the device and how can I launch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. Havent tried but might work

```
final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file); 
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"); 

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if(list.size() > 0)
   startActivity(context, intent);
```

Comment: The file is in the raw folder of the app. Which uri do I have to use (I am new to android, so excuse me, if this question is stupid).

Comment: It is possible to send from raw folder but lots of apps do not correctly handle the uri permissions granted, so better approach would be to copy the file to internal /external memory and then pass the uri

Comment: How can you do this? I can just find possibilities to copy files from the internal to the external storage, but not to copy files from the raw-folder.

Comment: You can use Resources.openRawResource to get the stream, and copy byte by byte to an external file using OpenFileOutput

Comment: When I try to write the file to the external cache, it somehow gets corrupted and I cannot open it anymore. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is it possible to open the ppt files within my own app ?
Are there any such open source components available ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    File file = new File("path_to_the_file.ppt");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
startActivity(intent);
```

try with this